# String Normalization in Java

Tags: java, string, normalization

I am trying to write a program the reads words from a text file and inserts the  uniquely into an array while keeping a separate count  for each word. Also I need to strip off the punctuation and move all the letters to lowercase.

Can anyone please help it will be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class text {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        try 
        {           
            String currentWord,normalizedWord;
            String word [] = new String [1000];
            int freq [] = new int [1000];
            int wCnt = 0;
            int loc;
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

            //get the name of the file
            System.out.print("Enter the name of a file:");
            String filename = kb.nextLine();

            //Open file
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);          

            while(inputFile.hasNext()){

                currentWord = inputFile.next();
                normalizedWord = normalize(currentWord);
                System.out.println("The normalized word is: " + normalizedWord);
                loc = search(word,wCnt,normalizedWord);
                print(word,wCnt);
                if(loc == -1){

                    insertUnique(word, freq, wCnt, normalizedWord);

                    freq[loc]++;
                    wCnt++;                 
                }

                else
                    freq[loc]++;                
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void print(String[] word, int wCnt) {
            System.out.print("{ ");

            for (int i=0; i < wCnt; i++)
                System.out.print(word[i] + " , ");


                System.out.print("}");
            }               



    public static int search(String[] word, int wCnt, String normalizedWord)      {
        for (int i = 0; i < wCnt; i++){
            if (word[i]==normalizedWord)
                return i;                   
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int insertUnique(String[] word, int[] freq, int wCnt,
            String normalizedWord) {
        if(!isIn(word,wCnt,normalizedWord)){
            word[wCnt] = normalizedWord;
            wCnt++;
        }
        return wCnt;
    }

    public static boolean isIn(String[] word, int wCnt, String normalizedWord) {

        for (int i = 0; i < wCnt; i++){
            if(word[i]== normalizedWord)
                return true;
        }
                return false;
    }

    public static String normalize(String wrd) {

        if (wrd.charAt(0) == '"' )             
            wrd = wrd.substring(1);            

        int wrdLength = wrd.length();

        //To remove all punctuation
        if (wrd.charAt(wrdLength-1) == '"')         
            wrd = wrd.substring(0,wrdLength -1);    

        //To remove all punctuation
        if (wrd.charAt(wrdLength-1) == '?')
            wrd = wrd.substring(0,wrdLength -1);        
        return wrd;
   }        
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? So far your question reads as "write a code for me".

Comment: I am trying to remove punctuation and make all uppercase to lowercase

Comment: i am trying to write a program the reads words from a text file and inserts the uniquely into an array while keeping a separate count for each word. Also i need to strip off the punctuation and move all the letters to lowercase

Comment: So, what is your problem then?

Comment: Why don't you use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` with your word as the key and your count as the value.

Comment: I am stuck trying to get rid of punctuation. I will research what you are talking about Alexander_Winter thanks for your suggestion but I am still a novice so I don't exactly know what a HashMap is.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter I really don't understand the HashMap class does it strip my word of punctuation?

Comment: @Clay Nope, I mean you can use the HashMap to save your Strings. You can use String.replace to get rid of the punctation.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter I still don't get hashmap but can you take a look I thought I was close then next thing you know I have an error that I cant locate

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with HashMap.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "a b, c a a. d e f? f e d! c a";
        // replace punctutation
        sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[.!?,]", "");
        String[] splittedSentence = sentence.split("\\s");
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String word : splittedSentence) {
            // move all letters to lowercase
            word = word.toLowerCase();

            // count words
            if (wordmap.get(word) != null) {
                wordmap.put(word, wordmap.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                wordmap.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(wordmap);
    }
```

Output:

`{a=4, b=1, c=2, d=2, e=2, f=2}`